# I have to proof that the integral converge for all p >0

Tags: special-functions, integral-equations, convergence-divergence

$$\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x} x^{p-1} dx$$

I guess I should have used the sharing criterion but I'm new to this and I don't know how it works, I understand the graph of $g(x)$ which is greater than $f(x)$ but it's confusing to apply, less for me.

Sorry for my english, I'm from Colombia I do my best.

Comment: I suspect what you call the sharing criterion has a different name in English. Could you link to an explanation of it?

Comment: Obviously, you only need to handle $p < 1$ case. But since $1 < e^{-x} < e^{-1}$ in the stated range, your integral is bounded above and below by multiples of $\int\limits_0^1 dt\ t^{p - 1} = \frac{t^p}{p}\Big|_0^1=....$

Comment: Sorry, i mean "comparison criteria" @J.G.

Comment: In that case, @WilliamM.'s hint is all you need.